# Call function again if array

Tags: php

I got a router in my MVC, it works fine but I think it can be shortened twice because anything beside of `if (is_array($path))` and after `else` is the same

Currently I just copied code when condition `is_array` returns true and use `foreach` to loop through `$path`. When condition `is_array` is false it just use `else` statement.

```
public function run()
    {

        // Get string of query
        $uri = $this->getURI();

        // Check availability of query in routes.php
        foreach ($this->routes as $uriPattern => $path) {

                // Compare $uriPattern and $uri
                if (preg_match("~$uriPattern~", $uri)) {


                        if (is_array($path)) {

                            foreach ($path as $p) {
                  //***logic here***
                            }
                        } else {
                  //***same logic here but for a string***
}
```

Currently my code is bigger than it should because 50% of it just a copy af itself. Can you suggest what would be a more  elegant way to split array and loop though paths? I thought about recursion but kinda don't know how to apply it in this case.

Thanks

Comment: Put the logic into a new function and re-use it

Comment: Yes, `do_logic($p);`  else `do_logic($path);`

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function run()
    {
        $uri = $this->getURI();

        foreach ($this->routes as $uriPattern => $path) {
            if (preg_match("~$uriPattern~", $uri)) {
                if (!is_array($path)) {
                    $path = [$path];
                }

                foreach ($path as $p) {
                    do_logic($p);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```